# How to load cache file? for image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

after upload photo to the app, i want to use very same photo for image_paint. this is my code

```
Center(
               // this button is used to open the image picker
               child: ElevatedButton(
               onPressed:  ()async {
               // call dialog and get value "camera" or "galery"
               final type = await  _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
               if(type != null){
               // call image pikcer
              final pickedFile = await _openImagePicker(type);
                if(pickedFile !=null){ 
                   // set here
                   setState(()
                       
                     {_image = pickedFile;});
                 }
                }
              },
               child: const Text('Select An Image'),),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                //call image painter here
                onPressed: ()async{
                   Navigator.push(
                      context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImagePainterExample(image: _image,)),
               );
          

                }, 
                child: const Text ('Paint Image'),)
```

this is the code where i put file? i call paint_image class with same file? as parameters,

```
class ImagePainterExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImagePainterExample({super.key, required this.image});
  final File? image;

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ImagePainterExampleState createState() => _ImagePainterExampleState(image_1: image);
}

class _ImagePainterExampleState extends State<ImagePainterExample> {
  final _imageKey = GlobalKey<ImagePainterState>();
  final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   _ImagePainterExampleState({required this.image_1});
  File? image_1;

  void saveImage() async {
    final image = await _imageKey.currentState?.exportImage();
    final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    await Directory('$directory/sample').create(recursive: true);
    final fullPath =
        '$directory/sample/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
    final imgFile = File(fullPath);
    imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(image!);
    await GallerySaver.saveImage(fullPath, toDcim: true);
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        content: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text("Image Exported successfully.",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => OpenFile.open(fullPath),
              child: Text(
                "Open",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stringfile = image_1.toString();
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Image Painter Example"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save_alt),
            onPressed: saveImage,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ImagePainter.asset(
        stringfile,
        key: _imageKey,
        scalable: true,
        initialStrokeWidth: 2,
        initialColor: Colors.green,
        initialPaintMode: PaintMode.line,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my code for image_paint, i want to use that file? image to paint, it come out error unable to load file?, how i do fix that?

Comment: Why are you passing image as image_1 to state, you can use the image in the state by 'widget.image'.

Comment: @user10061998 where to apply that in the code?